# Document stacking context root element: <body> or <html>?

Tags: html, css, z-index

Here's what I know:

- In HTML, the document's root element is `<html>`
- A document's root element creates a stacking context, hence `<html>` is the root element of the first stacking context created in any HTML document

From this, I'd expect any `z-index: -1` element to be positioned behind `<body>` (though in front of `<html>`) in a document where no other stacking context comes into play.
The following example, however, demonstrates otherwise in all modern browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/39q2u/

I've dug a little deeper in that second example: http://jsfiddle.net/39q2u/1/

1. Adding a `background-color` to `<html>` somehow makes the rendering engine realize that the `z-index: -1` element should indeed be displayed behind `<body>`, effectively making it invisible since `<body>` also has a `background-color` set.

   Interestingly, I've given a try to several other CSS properties, an none of them seem to have the same effect.

   (The element remains visible in IE 9.)
2. Removing the `background-color` from `<body>` makes the `z-index: -1` element appear again, proving it was hidden behind `<body>`.

The issue I'm having with this is *how to make sense of that behavior*:

- Is `<body>` subject to additional rules when it comes to stacking contexts?
- Why is it needed to set a `background-color` on `<html>` for the rendering engine to behave correctly?
- Or did I just misunderstand something, somewhere?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#special-backgrounds

Comment: The fact that `<html>` sometimes gets background properties from `<body>` is something I had overlooked and taken for granted for a long time, so thanks for that link. I'm not sure how that relates to the issue at hand though.

Comment: Coming back to this question today, and taking another look at the part of the spec @thirtydot linked to, I now believe it actually explains the observed behavior. As I read it now, the document's canvas requires a background at all times. If no background is set on `html`, the background from `body` will be used instead; not only that, but it'll also set `body`'s background transparent. That explains why a `z-index: -1` element is only hidden behind `body` when a background is explicitly set on both `html` and `body`. The surprise didn't come from the stacking order, it came from backgrounds.

Comment: @thirtydot Feel free to post an answer to this question, I'll accept it. Thanks again for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The default `background-color` of `html` is `transparent`. Thus, elements with a negative `z-index` are displayed, because you can see them "through" the `html` element. The link provided by @thirtydot points toward the right direction, although perhaps this link: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-color might be more on point.

Comment: `<html>` is the root element of a stacking context, so if any `z-index: -1` element within that stacking context is visible, it's because it's displayed over that root element despite the negative `z-index` (see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html#painting-order). Even if it were the case, it wouldn't explain why the `z-index: -1` element is displayed over `<body>`.

Comment: Actually, that link says it in step 2: If the element is a block, list-item, or other block equivalent:
background color of element unless it is the root element.

Comment: After re-reading that part of the spec, my understanding of the stacking context painting order doesn't change: `<html>` background color, negative `z-index` element, then `<body>` and its background color. Hence my original question: why is the negative `z-index` element visible in front of `<body>`? If you have a different interpretation of the spec, I'm eager to hear it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that last comment got posted accidentally. I was re-reading the spec and was puzzling over step 8, when I pressed Enter, and my focus was still on this window. I'm puzzled about this one as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I believe the body tag always follows a z-index which is relative to other elements to make it easier when ordering multiple elements on the page.

If you apply an attribute to html, it suddenly becomes, and behaves like any other element, therefore putting it's child element,  tag, into use as an element on the page also. Think of it as if you have toys you can play with, then toys you cannot reach. By assigning an attribute to the html, you are bringing the toys you could not reach into reaching distance. You are allowing the webpage to use the  and subsequently the

That made sense in my head but I am stood from a bias stance so I hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

actually your expectation working as described except for the background property

take a look at this snippet it a prove that `p` element under body after positioned with negative integer :

```css
html{
    border: 20px solid green;
    width: 250px
}
body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
  width: 200px;
  border: 20px solid orange;
  overflow: hidden;
  background:red;
}
p {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
 <p>helllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllo</p>
```

so we can now exclude `z-index` from reasons

and It looks like a weird behavior on `background-color` property 
I think it's better to read about it by following this links :

https://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/

[Giving background-color to body applying whole page. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300463/giving-background-color-to-body-applying-whole-page-why)