# Giving background-color to body applying whole page. Why?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Hello World!</div>
</body>
```

So the `background-color: red;` applies to whole page height but when I inspect the page the height of the body is only up to the `div` containing **Hello World!**.

Someone please explain this why it is happening like this.

Comment: because you applied background only for body

Comment: That's what I am asking. The height of the body is not the entire page but bg color is applying to the height of the entire page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background-Color of BODY tag applied to the whole HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806691/background-color-of-body-tag-applied-to-the-whole-html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The main reason is because the `HTML` takes the `background-color` of `BODY` since:

> The background of the root element becomes the background of the
>   canvas and covers the entire canvas [...]

So since the default `background-color` of `HTML` is `transparent` it will take the one from `BODY`. However applying a color to both the `HTML` and `BODY` elements you will see that the `BODY` background doesn't cover the whole page anymore.

```css
html {
  background-color: blue;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>Hello World!</div>
</body>

</html>
```

> The background of the root element becomes the background of the
>   canvas and covers the entire canvas, anchored (for
>   `background-position`) at the same point as it would be if it was
>   painted only for the root element itself. The root element does not
>   paint this background again.
>
> For HTML documents, however, we recommend that authors specify the
>   background for the `BODY` element rather than the `HTML` element. For
>   documents whose root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML
>   "html" element that has computed values of `transparent` for
>   `background-color` and `none` for `background-image`, user agents must
>   instead use the computed value of the background properties from that
>   element's first HTML "BODY" element or XHTML "body" element child when
>   painting backgrounds for the canvas, and must not paint a background
>   for that child element. Such backgrounds must also be anchored at the
>   same point as they would be if they were painted only for the root
>   element.

<sub>From [W3 -  14 Colors and Backgrounds](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

it's actually pretty logic. First of all `<html>` and `<body>` tags are required tags in a webpage. Where the `<html>` tag contains all of the `<html>` code the `<body>` tag holds all of the contents.

Consider this standard structure for a basic `HTML` document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Metadata and such -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Where the content begins -->
  <body>

</html>
```

The spec defines `<html>` as the root element of a document, and we can clearly see that in the above example: the  element is the very top level of all other elements. The buck stops there because there are no more levels beyond that from which styles can be inherited.

From there,  and  make up the only two elements that fall directly inside . In fact, the spec defines  directly in contrast to  since those are the only two elements that need to be distinguished.

So, the bottom line here is that  is the root element of a document where  is a descendent contained within it. In fact, there is a :root selector in CSS. These target the exact same thing.

It's tempting to think that any styles we want to be inherited across the board should be applied directly to `<html>` because it is the root element of the document. `<html>` supersedes `<body>` in hierarchy, so it follows that it must contain all global styles.

But that's not exactly the case. In fact, inline attributes for the following were originally assigned to `<body>` in the spec:

- background
- bgcolor
- marginbottom
- marginleft
- marginright
- margintop
- text

**The background-color**

There is a weird thing in `CSS` where the `background-color` on `<body>` floods the whole viewport even if the metrics of the element itself don't cover that whole area. Unless the `background-color` gets set on the html element, then it doesn't.

If flooding is the goal, it can be smart to just set it on the `html` element to begin with.

Comment: Is an HTML keyword missing in this line: "The spec defines as the root element of a document" . The sentence does not make sense.

For that matter, read the whole answer -- there are multiple instances such as above.

Comment: @Nikhil bit of a late response, but yes it was a typo. I tried to mention a code tag but forgot the backticks. And that's why it didn't show up at all in the first place. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

CSS tricks has a related post in merit [link](https://css-tricks.com/html-vs-body-in-css/#article-header-id-1) . It seems that body styles are expanded to html because:

> html is the root element of a document where body is a descendent
>   contained within it. In fact, there is a :root selector in CSS. These
>   target the exact same thing

Answer (score 1):

> height you see in inspect is `min-height` That is equal  height's element `div`, background-color change `max-height` That is equal 100% his parents(html).

**For Example:**

change `min-height` and run inspect and see result :

```css
body {
   background-color: red;
   min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello World!</div>
```

> So, You see height in inspect Change `200px;` But color red cover whole page.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.some{

    background-color: red;

}
```

```html
<div class="some">Hello World!</div>
```

try this, as if you give color to body the whole webpage will be colored

Comment: I am asking the reason why full body/page bg getting red even if the height of the body is not that height

Comment: the default is the whole page, the normal screen hieght and width of your screen

Answer (score 0):

Body means all page that display in the browser. so you want give color only to div you can use either a id or a class to give a style to that dive. as in first answer.

```
<body>
    <div class="some">Hello World!</div>
</body>

.some{
   background-color: red;
}
```

or

```
<body>
    <div id="some">Hello World!</div>
</body>

#some{
   background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default browser remaining screen(viewport) will take background color of `<body>` element if  the background color in `<html>` element is not defined.

```
body{
  background-color:red;                   /*background will be red*/
}
```

If background color in `<html>` element is defined then remaining viewport will take background color of `<html> element`.

```
html{
  background:blue;            
}
                                /*background will be blue*/
body{
  background:red;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).