# Chrome dev tools not highlighting entire body?

Tags: css, position, google-chrome-devtools

I'm wondering if this is a bug or (more likely) a misunderstanding in using the dev tools / CSS. I was playing around with a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oy7utd21/) with the following style:

```
div.notrelative {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #eaf;
    margin: 50px;
    font-size: 9px;
    position:relative;
    font-family: Arial;
}
body {
    margin:30px;
}
div.absolute {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #eea;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
```

and I was looking at the highlighted areas in dev tools both on JSFiddle and on a local copy, and I noticed something strange. Chrome was only highlighting a portion of the body in blue (after the top margin by the *child* element but strangely not the left margin), despite the body taking up the entire page (as seen by the gray background color). However, just creating something simple like a border around the body completely seems to fix the highlighting issue. Is there a reason why Chrome highlights differently in the two cases?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Looking at your jsfiddle I see it depends on the active context (top or iframe) which is shown in the console's top toolbar, and is changed by clicking inside the DOM tree. When the top context is active and you track inside the iframe, the entire iframe is highlighted reagrdless of the element you hover. I'd say this is confusing and might warrant submitting a bug report on https://crbug.com

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the help. I see what you mean. However, even in the case when reproducing locally (no iframe), there's that weird part about only a portion of the view being highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) causes `div.notrelative` to extend its margins outside of `<body>` vertically and push `<html>` to be bigger than `<body>`. Thus, when you highlight `<body>`, the area beyond `<body>` but within `<html>` is not highlighted. That unhighlighted area represents the margins of `div.notrelative`. Adding borders prevents margin collapsing in the case of parent and first/last child.

As for why that area outside `<body>` is affected by its background-color, based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300463/giving-background-color-to-body-applying-whole-page-why), it is because `<html>` takes the background-color of `<body>`.

Comment: Thanks for your response1 I'm a bit confused how `notrelative` is extending its margin outside of body vertically—why wouldn't body, by default, enclose the `notrelative` tag even though it is set to be `position:relative`? (Sorry, that tag name is misleading and actually `notrelative` is positioned relative—I should've changed that).

Comment: After some research, turns out it's due to margin collapsing. I've edited the answer so it explains it better. Hope this helps.