# why does background-color property fills the entire screen even body have 0 height?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, background-color, document-body

Can anyone explain why the background color is filling the entire screen even when body is having zero height?

```css
.bgcolor { 
  background-color : red;
  height:0;
}
```

```html
<body class="bgcolor"></body>
```

Comment: can't see and background here

Comment: I made a snippet and changed your code to `.bgcolor { background-color : red; }` to show the issue

Comment: that would be due to the browser's default CSS - in Chrome I see `body {
    display: block;
    margin: 8px;
}`

Comment: You're not establishing any other attributes? like height, width, display, etc...

Comment: This will simply Answer your Queries [Giving background-color to body applying whole page. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44301236/15405352)

Comment: but height is zero than how can the complete screen becomes red.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Giving background-color to body applying whole page. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300463/giving-background-color-to-body-applying-whole-page-why) , [Background-Color of BODY tag applied to the whole HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806691/background-color-of-body-tag-applied-to-the-whole-html),  [Other duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body) + [W3 Doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#:~:text=The%20background%20of%20the%20root,not%20paint%20this%20background%20again.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

body tag is always taking the whole document's body, so if you want to give background with limited height then put one DIV inside the body tag and then give specific height, then it will work fine.

so for the solution, please give background color to HTML div as well.

```
html {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: No i think that body tag without any content will have zero height.